# Change values from a dataset variable in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new in Bash and I am trying to change the values of a column from the file data.csv coma delimitted.

In the dataset I have the variable `sex` with only 2 possible values `'Female'` and `'Male'` and I would like to transform Male into 'm' and Female into 'f'.
I have tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sex=$(cut -d , -f 5 data.csv) #I select column 5 related with the variable sex
for i in $sex; do
    if [[$i='Female']]; then
    $i='f'
    fin
done
```

The code is wrong and I do not know how to modify it.

Besides, I would like to update my `data.csv` with the new values in sex.

Comment: Paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net -- it will help you through the syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# awk
# without header
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{$5=="Male" ? $5="m" : $5="f"}1' data.csv > output1.csv
# with header
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} NR!=1{$5=="Male" ? $5="m" : $5="f"}1' data.csv > output1.csv
```

---

```
# bash
while read line 
do
    line=${line/,Male,/,m,}
    line=${line/,Female,/,f,}
    echo $line
done  < data.csv > output2.csv
```

---

```
# sed
sed 's/,Male,/,m,/; s/,Female,/,f,/' data.csv > output3.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '
$5 == "Female" {$5 = "f"}
$5 == "Male" {$5 = "m"} 1' data.csv
```